# How to remove the shadow under Action bar

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have been trying to get the shadow under the app Action bar to disappear but it wont which is very annoying. iI have set the theme to NoActionBar and opted to using toolbar instead.

[image]

**And have i have also set the elevation to 0dp in my activity.java**

```java
package com.example.drawerlayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private AppBarLayout actionLayout;
    private Toolbar t;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

    }
}
```

**The Toolbar looks thus:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/nav_action"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/mm_blue" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: refer to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423211/remove-action-bar-shadow

Comment: put elevation to 0dp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this property `toolbar:elevation="0dp"` to `AppBarLayout` to remove shadow from `Toolbar`.
eg-

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        toolbar:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/nav_action"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/mm_blue" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: i think the shadow may be coming from my cardView or something as i have tried all that to no avail. i did set the whole background to blue and there was no shadow but putting the cardView back on i get that little tiny line

Comment: If you are showing CardView below the Toolbar then, I think you should remove card view shadow as well to remove this tiny line.

Comment: Done. i have been to remove it by setting  app:cardElevation to 0dp.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `app:elevation="0dp"`

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <!-- Toolbar -->

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:elevation="0dp">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/nav_action"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/mm_blue" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the AppBar layout and directly put your toolbar in the coordinate layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/nav_action"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/mm_blue" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Try this may it should help you out.